# How to assign specific command with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to asigne the **ctr+s** to save a Entry in a Tkinter program, but I don't even found it in the docs. Is there any possibility to do something like this :

```
def save():
   name = entry.get()
   text=textinput.get()
   file = open("./"+name,"w")
   file.write(text)
   file.close()

entry = Entry(window)
textinput = Text(window)
entry.pack()
textinput.pack()

--> asigne the 'save' command as 'ctr+s'
```

Please someone help me???

Comment: The `bind` method of widgets is well documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to bind `Ctrl-S` to a function

```
name_of_widget.bind("<Control-S>", save)
```